# How to stretch and center an unordered list?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I want the `ul` in `nav` to take up 66% of the page width, and the six items inside can then be given width accordingly.

Here is the problem, I am coding with my screen at 1024 to start with, but when I stretch the page wider, the `ul` does not stretch and does not take up the 66% of the page, and the `li` items do not stretch wider as well, so the proportions are lost.

```css
nav {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 12.5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 12.5px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  width: 66%;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 11%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /*Bottom margin to ensure that they do not get stuck together when the screen is squashed*/
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1.6px 1.6px #3e3e3e;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>HOME</li>
    <li>SHOP</li>
    <li>NEWS</li>
    <li>ABOUT US</li>
    <li>CONTACT US</li>
    <li>SUBSCRIBE</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use flexbox:

```
nav ul {
  display: flex; /*declare flexbox*/
  justify-content: space-between; /*space between items*/
  width: 66%; /*percentage width*/
  margin: 0 auto; /*center horizontally*/
  padding: 0; /*reset default padding*/
}
```

**[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XZZvLB)**

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using flexbox.

```
nav {
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 12.5px;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-top: 12.5px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
 width: 66%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: start;
 flex-direction: row;
}
```

A good start for flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/